# Get-ChildItem Memory Overflow

Tags: powershell

I am trying to clean up our file share and want to export a list of all our files older than 7 Years to present before approval for removal.

So far I have:

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\Shares\" -Recurse -File | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddYears(-7)} | select fullname,LastWriteTime,@{n='Length';e={$_.length / 1MB}}  | Export-Csv “C:\OldFiles.csv” -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

Now this nearly immediately runs out of memory, as its caching every file it finds. Is there a way to make this just export-csv -append each item so its not holding it in memory the whole time?

Comment: Your pipeline does _not_ cache every file it finds, so there must be something else going on. _Conceivably_, memory pressure due to pending garbage collection can build up, but that wouldn't surface nearly immediately.

Comment: What happens when you reduce the command to: `Get-ChildItem "D:\Shares\" -Recurse -File | Out-Null`?

Comment: If I pipe it to Out-Null, the command runs until complete and does not crash.

Comment: I figured out the problem, Its actually hitting a folder with a " " for a name and crashing.